# I got error installing guzzlehttp/guzzle in in laravel 5.8 app

Tags: laravel

I need to install guzzlehttp/guzzle to work with stripe in laravel 5.8 app but I got

error with installing :

```
$ composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
Warning from https://repo.packagist.org: You are using an outdated version of Composer. Composer 2 is now available and you should upgrade. See https://getcomposer.org/2
Using version ^7.2 for guzzlehttp/guzzle
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Warning from https://repo.packagist.org: You are using an outdated version of Composer. Composer 2 is now available and you should upgrade. See https://getcomposer.org/2
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for php-http/guzzle6-adapter (locked at v1.1.1, required as ^1.0) -> satisfiable by php-http/guzzle6-adapter[v1.1.1].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[7.2.0, 6.5.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[7.3.x-dev, 6.5.x-dev].
    - Conclusion: install guzzlehttp/guzzle 6.5.x-dev
    - Installation request for guzzlehttp/guzzle ^7.2 -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[7.2.0, 7.3.x-dev].
```

My composer.json has :

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2",
        "clarification/sendgrid-laravel-driver": "^2.0",
        "darkaonline/l5-swagger": "5.8.*",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "jenssegers/agent": "^2.6",
        "laravel/framework": "5.8.38",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "martinlindhe/laravel-vue-i18n-generator": "^0.1.46",
        "paragonie/sodium_compat": "^1.14",
        "php-http/guzzle6-adapter": "^1.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^5.x",
        "pusher/pusher-php-server": "^4.1.1",
        "stripe/stripe-php": "^7.50",
        "tintnaingwin/email-checker": "^2.0",
        "spatie/browsershot": "^3.37",
        "twilio/sdk": "^5.42"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.5"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "app/library/helper.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

I use PHP 7.4.15 .

How can it be fixed ?

Thanks!

Comment: did you run `composer update`?

Comment: Yes I run composer update (without modifing composer.json manually) with success. Have I to edit composer.json at first? If yes, how?

Comment: change `"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^5.x",`to this `"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2.0",`  and then run `composer update` and your current php version is `^7.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update the version of your guzzlehttp/guzzle becasue it is required by php version

Try to Change `"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^5.x"` to this `"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2.0"` and then run `composer update` and your current php version is ^7.2

you can find more about it in here https://packagist.org/packages/guzzlehttp/guzzle#6.5.5

Answer (score 0):

There is a conflict with the lastest version, use this instead

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle:^7.0
```